# Azure AD Front-channel logout URL and SameSite cookie in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, webforms, openid-connect, owin

I've been investigating implementing Azure AD for an old web forms ASP.NET application and came across an issue when trying to use single sign out via the Front-channel logout URL in the App registration.

By default this wasn't working due to how Azure AD loads the request in an iframe, which won't allow the cookies to be sent in the logout request, so the request would fire but it would have no user association because the auth cookies were absent.

I came across an article describing the situation:
https://joonasw.net/view/aad-single-sign-out-in-asp-net-core

Here it describes needing to set the SameSite property to None on the auth cookie so that it gets included in the logout request, which did in fact work, it was able to logout the user who made the request and clear their cookies from my app when logging out from another Azure AD app:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        { CookieSameSite = Microsoft.Owin.SameSiteMode.None });
```

My question is, something seems off about this fix, does this not open up CSFR attacks by allowing the auth cookie to be sent in any request? Is there another solution or any way to keep SameSite strict but somehow allow login.microsoftonline.com to send the app's auth cookie?

Comment: _"does this not open up CSFR attacks by allowing the auth cookie to be sent in any request?"_ - it can do, that's why a (better-designed system) has two separate auth cookies: one with `SameSite.None`, which only permits "safe" read-only operations (`GET`, etc), while another cookie (with `SameSite.Lax`) is required for "unsafe" operations (POST, et al), it can be combined with a CORS policy to deny `POST` requests. Doing this will require rearchitecturing your application's authX system and probably won't be worth it in most cases. An alternative is to require an antiforgery token for POST.

Comment: I get what you're saying but I don't think this is possible with the Microsoft.IdentityModel/OWIN/OIDC libraries in .NET. AD issues the cookie so that would be the only one tracked both in AD & the client, and calling HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut() wouldn't find the cookie it's looking for

Comment: You should only be calling `SignOut` in response to a (CSRF-protected) POST request (the `GET` request would be for a HTML `<form>` to confirm the sign-out - or otherwise have a 1-liner of JS that submits the form on the `load` event (so users don't notice the POST).

Comment: Be aware also that blocking third party cookies in iframes will eventually become the default in Chrome and Edge which further limits the usefulness of front channel logout. The OIDC spec now includes a back channel mechanism (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) that solves this problem but it's not supported by Azure AD/Entra ID at this time as far as I know. I'd definitely recommend planning your implementations with this in mind as it's not a good look to ask your users to downgrade sensible privacy defaults in their browser to use your app.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of cookie to consider here:

**THIRD PARTY COOKIES**

Cookies issued by an identity system such as Azure AD use `SameSite=None`. When a web application performs an OAuth login operation, this allows such cookies to be sent in a top level redirect `when the user can view the identity domain` in the browser URL. This will work in all browsers.

If such cookies are sent from iframes or Ajax requests, they are likely to be dropped, due to restrictions introduced in [RFC6265bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/), which introduced Same Site cookie restrictions. This is an initiative to protect user privacy and prevent unwelcome tracking. Some browsers go beyond the spec. One example is Safari, whose default settings will drop such cookies if they are sent in iframe or Ajax requests.

Therefore, some OAuth flows that previously worked, such as background token renewal on an iframe, session management, and front channel single logout, are no longer viable. They use cookies in iframes, the user is not informed, and cookies will be dropped, in at least some browsers. There is nothing you can do in code to make such flows work in all browsers.

**FIRST PARTY COOKIES**

Meanwhile a web application's own cookies should use the strongest SameSite setting, with the best protection against cross site request forgery. So prefer this setting in your ASP.NET application:

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        { CookieSameSite = Microsoft.Owin.SameSiteMode.Strict });
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, I understand the difference between 1st/3rd party cookies, I suppose I'm wondering why MS would offer a feature that required your app to set insecure cookie properties, or if I was missing something. The front channel logout does pass 'sid' I thought maybe I could invalidate the user session but their cookie would still remain. Is there a way to enable single signout via webforms or should I just give up on this feature?

Comment: @n4esa _"I suppose I'm wondering why MS would offer a feature that required your app to set insecure cookie properties"_ - because MS needs to support decades worth of (often internal-only) enterprise applications that would be broken by improving browser security standards meant for the public web.

Comment: I usually recommend sticking to plain OIDC RP initiated logout, since that will work reliably, whereas SLO solutions have reliability issues these days, as described above.